# How to add selected users to OG Group from field selection when creating group

Tags: rules, organic-groups

I have an OG and a field that lists users with checkboxes. Is there a way using Rules, to add the selected users as group members when group is saved/updated?

Comment: I'm nowhere... I'm stuck at getting the values from the field that contains user . names

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223738/39516), which IMO is a variation of what you're asking for. Does that help somehow?

Comment: Looking at your answer it seems you made major progress as compared to your prior comment, well done! Did my hint (link) in my prior comment help you somehow to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rule I created to solved it:

1. After updating/adding existing content of type
2. Entity has field Parameter: Entity: [node], Field: FIELD WITH UNAMES
3. Crete a LOOP
4. (In Loop) Subscribe user to group -- Parameter: User: [list-item],
   Group: [site:og-context--node]

Here is an export of my rule:

```
{ "rules_watch_list_group_add" : {
  "LABEL" : "Watch List Group Add",
  "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
  "OWNER" : "rules",
  "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "og" ]
  "ON" : { "node_insert" : [], "node_update" : [] },
  "IF" : [
    { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_watch_list" } }
  ],
  "DO" : [
    { "LOOP" : {
        "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:field-watch-list" ] },
        "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
        "DO" : [
          { "og_subcribe_user" : { "user" : [ "list-item" ], "group" : [ "site:og-context--node" ] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the real answer... these are the four things I did to get it working

Comment: Minor remark: bullet 1 seems to not match with your actual Rules Event ...